# Use NDepend to check if a method calls the base.Method at the end

Tags: ndepend

I've to check if the `base.InitializeAsync` is called as the latest line of code at the method's end.

Consider the following code

```
  protected override async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        CalculateTotals();
        await base.InitializeAsync();
    }
```

That's ok

```
  protected override async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await base.InitializeAsync();
        CalculateTotals();
    }
```

That's not.

Is this possible with NDepend?

Comment: you can check if the method is called, but you cannot check the method call order